# C++ Passing arguments to a function

Tags: c++, function, declaration

Recently i started to program in C/C++, but i find it a little bit hard to understand certain things. For example, my vertices.h file:

```
#ifndef _vertices_h
#define _vertices_h

typedef struct
{
    float XYZW[4];
    float RGBA[4];
} Vertex;

extern Vertex Vertices[];
extern GLubyte Indices[];

#endif
```

And my vertices.c file:

```
#include "vertices.h"

Vertex Vertices[] =
{
    { { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } }       
};
GLubyte Indices[] = {
    0, 1, 3,
    0, 3, 2,
    3, 1, 4,
    3, 4, 2
 };
```

Not, i need to create a function in other .h file that will use my Vertices array. Here is the shader.c file:

```
#include "vertices.h"

void CreateVBO(){ #############################################1
// some operations that uses the passed Vertices array
}
```

and my "shaders.h" file:

```
#ifndef _shaders_h
#define _shaders_h

void CreateVBO(); #############################################################2

#endif
```

Now my question is, in my main function i call the function CreateVBO, and i want to pass it the Vertices Array i need. In my case, i'v only declared 1, but i want to declare more and pass in the one i want. So basically, i dont really know how to declare arguments of the function CreateVBO. The lines i'm missing are signed with ####.

```
void doSemthing(int argc, char* argv[]){
...
CreateVBO(); #############################################################3
}
```

Comment: So, you mean, you want to know how function arguments work? Did your C++ book somehow fail to adequately cover this topic in its earliest chapters? You should get a new one then.

Comment: Your `Vertices` and `Indices` arrays are global objects. `CreateVBO` can access them already without you passing any arguments.

Comment: ok. but what if i want the same function CreateVBO to use another array? I cannot do that without setting in the arguments can i?

Comment: @sftrabbit: `but i want to declare more and pass in the one i want`

Comment: "I started programming in C/C++" - I don't know of any language with this name, but it must be my fault, since a lot of *talented and experienced* programmers around here seem to be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vertices[]` is global and you don't need pass it through parameter. However you can pass vertices too.

Make your function as below

```
void CreateVBO(Vertex vertices[]);
```

call it

```
CreateVBO(Vertices);
```

Comment: what about the .h declaration of that function. can i leave it void? and in your answer, shouldnt it be: "Vertex Vertices[] with full 'V' ?

Comment: You must change declaration of `CreateVBO` in both `.h` and `.cpp`

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't seem clear to me, although I'm assuming that you are to more declare elements to the array " Vertices[ ] " and you want to pass any one of them to " CreateVBO() ".

Suppose you declared " Vertices[ ] " in " vertices.h " as :

```
Vertices[index1] = {...something....};    // Vertices with index1 elements.
```

Now in the  "shaders.h" file you can declare and define CreateVBO() as :

```
void CreateVBO(Vertex *V)
{
    //....something....

    V[index1].XYZW[index2]   // You can access the variables as shown.
    V[index1].RGBA[index2]   // You can access the variables as shown.

    //....something....
}
```

And in " doSemthing() " Vertices can be passed to " CreateVBO() " as :

```
void doSemthing(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ...something....

    CreateVBO(Vertices);

    ...something....
}
```